# Creating a list of files and contents

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Trying to create a sort of vault. I have several .txt files with the account names containing the amount inside.

```
echo ______________________>current.txt 
::this bit just resets the file ^^ 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=1
for /f %%x in (list.txt) do (
  set "Line_!Counter!=%%x"
    set "temp=%%x"
    set /p amountIn=<%%x.txt
  set /a Counter+=1
echo %temp% vault contains>>current.txt
  )
```

When I run this I just get " Vault contains " in current.txt. and no errors inside the CMD.
To clarify, Current.txt is my output file that i want the list in, list.txt is a list of the bank accounts, and the directory has all of the bank accounts with numbers in them.

Comment: You could use `!temp!` instead of `%temp%`, or you could just use, `Echo %%x vault contains`. The latter is my recommendation, so that you don't create and change a variable with the same name as a system variable, `%temp%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment:

```bat
Echo ______________________>current.txt
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Counter=1"
For /F %%A In (list.txt) Do (
    Set "Line_!Counter!=%%A"
    Set "_tmp=%%A"
    Set /P "amountIn="<%%A.txt
    Set /A Counter +=1
    >>current.txt Echo !_tmp! vault contains !amountIn!
)
```

Or:

```bat
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Counter=0"
(
    For /F %%A In (list.txt) Do (
        Set /A Counter +=1
        Set "Line_!Counter!=%%A"
        Set /P "amountIn="<%%A.txt
        Echo %%A vault contains !amountIn!
    )
)>current.txt
```

Comment: Would like to point out spelling on that first line just in case someone else tries to use this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CrologMark, fixed!